# iOS and Android app advertising without using advertising identifier

Tags: android, ios, app-store-connect, idfa, google-advertising-id

I'm planning to build an iOS and Android app with custom advertising on some screen. The custom advertising does not use advertising identifier provided by iOS(IDFA) or Android.

my questions are for the app review from both Apple and google,

1. Should I still need to indicate that my app has advertising?
2. Is the use of advertising is mandatory in order to provide custom ad that does not use the advertising identifier?
3. Is it possible that Google or Apple reject the app if i don't use the Advertising identifier but still provide custom ad?

Comment: Apple only asks if you use the IDFA, not whether you have advertising.  Answer yes or no accordingly (You should answer NO).  Apple's own iAD did not use the IDFA so the correct answer was "No" even though there would be advertising.

Comment: Thank you for the information - @Paulw11